# Why „guter“ in „zu guter Letzt“?

Tags: meaning, declension

Two questions regarding “zu guter Letzt”?

(1) The comparative sequence of „gut“ is „gut/besser/am besten“ and a common beginner‘s mistake would be, „Mein Computer ist guter als deiner“ rather than „ Mein Computer ist besser als deiner.“ So then why does the common expression, „zu guter Letzt“ use „guter“ rather than „besser“? Is it because “guter” here is not a comparative but simply the declined adjective modifying the masculine (presumably) noun “Letzt”?
EDIT: Hmmm, “zu” takes the dative, so then I suppose “Letzt” would be feminine.

(2) The only instance of “Letzt” in two online dictionaries that I checked is in the phrase, “zu guter Letzt.” It does not appear to have any other function. Is that so? Where does it come from?

Many thanks.

Comment: For the first part you have already found the answer, and it is confirmed by a dictionary: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Letzt
I suggest that you remove that part and only ask the second question.

Answer (score 4):

"(die) Letzt" is a feminine noun which has only survived in standing phrases like in your example. Other than that, it's not commonly used.

"Guter" thus is a feminine dative singular adjective in positive aligned with the noun, not a comparative as you seem to assume. The dative is caused by the preposition "zu".

"Letzt" stems from the adjective "letzt" and denotes the end, the final point of something.